# sed replace only after condition is met

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have this myfile with lines:

```
dog
snake
dog
cat
dog    
snake
python
cat
dog  
cat
dog
```

This would replace all dog with lion
    sed -i 's/dog/lion/g'

but I want to make replacement only after the first "cat" is met in the file so to have

```
dog
snake
dog
cat
lion    
snake
python
cat
lion  
cat
lion
```

How can I do that?
Note that I do not know a priori in which line the first "cat" is. I have to find the first cat and then apply sed from there on

Answer (score 4):

Use a [*range address*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html):

```
sed '/cat/,$s/dog/lion/' a.txt
```

The range in this case starts at the first occurrence of `cat` and ends at the end of  the input, expressed by `/cat/,$`.

Answer (score 0):

translation of `sed` solution to `awk`

```
$ awk '/cat/,0{sub("dog","lion")}1' file
```

Explanation:

`/cat/,0` from cat to end of file

`sub("dog","lion")` replace dog with lion

`1` print

Answer (score 0):

An additional option to handle substituting `lion` for `dog` only if the preceding line is `cat` is:

```
sed "/cat/{N;s/dog/lion/;}"
```

For example, with your datafile saved as `file.txt`:

```
$ sed "/cat/{N;s/dog/lion/;}" file.txt
dog
snake
dog
cat
lion
snake
python
cat
lion
cat
lion
```